# Sort array by number of path components in value objective-c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, file, sorting, nsarray

I have an `nsarray` with file paths in it and I would like to sort it with the value that has the most path components at the top *(index at 0)*.

Here's my array before the sorting process:

```
Array (
    "/FIRST/SECOND/THIRD",
    "/FIRST/SECOND/MYFOLDER",
    "/FIRST/SECOND",
    "/FIRST/SECOND/MYFOLDER/PHOTOS"
)
```

Here's what I would like my array to look like after:

```
Array (
    "/FIRST/SECOND/MYFOLDER/PHOTOS",
    "/FIRST/SECOND/AWESOME",
    "/FIRST/SECOND/MYFOLDER",
    "/FIRST/SECOND"

)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the docs for `NSArray` and tried any of the many sorting methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the NSString method `-pathComponents` with a custom sort block and NSArray's `-sortedArrayUsingComparator:` to get a sorted copy of the array based on the number of path components in each string:

```
NSArray *sorted = [arrayBeforeSorting sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
                        NSUInteger count1 = [[obj1 pathComponents] count];
                        NSUInteger count2 = [[obj2 pathComponents] count];
                        if (count1 > count2) {
                            return NSOrderedAscending;
                        } else if (count1 < count2) {
                            return NSOrderedDescending;
                        } else {
                            return NSOrderedSame;
                        }
                    }];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How can I also sort by alphabetically at the same time?

Comment: @baileyseymour ... by replacing `NSOrderedSame` with `[obj1 compare:obj2]`.